# LINQ Distinct(), but programmatically select a winner

Tags: c#, linq

I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linqs-distinct-on-a-particular-property), regarding selecting a distinct item based on a particular property.

The following will look in my "results" list, group them by ID, and select the first one as the winner.

```
results.GroupBy(r => r.ID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

**But, how can I conditionally select the winner?**

For example, each result contains a property called *Language.Name*.

When selecting distinct results, I want to pick the one where `result.Language.Name.ToLower() == regionalISOCode` as the winner if it exists.

If it does not exist, then the `result.Language.Name.ToLower() == "en"` should be selected as the winner.

Comment: what`s the question again ?

Comment: `g.First()` is programmatically selecting the winner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to change the `Select()`:

```
results
    .GroupBy(r => r.ID)
    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Language.Name.ToLower() == regionalISOCode) ??
                 g.First(r => r.Language.Name.ToLower() == "en"))
    .ToList();
```